# Issue with tie and game over

Tags: python, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

I have implemented tic-tac-toe as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import font as tkFont

#initializes a 3x3 list named 'board' with empty strings as elements
board = [['' for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]

game_active = True

#defines the function to switch to the game screen
def play_game():

    #creates a top level window (appears above all other windows when pressed)
    game_window = tk.Toplevel(win)

    #sets the name of the new window to "Tic-Tac-Toe Game"
    game_window.title("Tic-Tac-Toe Game")

    #sets the size of the game window when opened to 600x600
    game_window.geometry("600x600")

    #doesn't allow the main game window to be resized
    game_window.resizable(False, False)


    #creates a canvas to draw lines
    canvas = tk.Canvas(game_window, width=600, height=600)
    canvas.pack()

    #creates horizontal lines
    for i in range(1, 3):
        canvas.create_line(0, i * 200, 600, i * 200, fill="black")

    #creates vertical lines
    for i in range(1, 3):
        canvas.create_line(i * 200, 0, i * 200, 600, fill="black")


    #creates the buttons in the game window, uses configure to later destroy the button after it has been pressed
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            x1 = i * 200
            y1 = j * 200
            button_tile = ttk.Button(game_window)
            button_tile.place(x=x1, y=y1, width=200, height=200)
            button_tile.configure(command=lambda row=i, col=j, btn=button_tile, parent=game_window: button_click(row, col, btn, parent))


#sets first turn of player to 'O' and next is 'X', so on and on
o_Turn = True



#defines the function what happens when one of the 9 buttons are pressed
def button_click(row, col, button, parent):

    #sets a global variable o_Turn so that it can be accessed anywhere - removing localerror
    global o_Turn

    #make the boolean variable an X or an O
    Sign = 'X'
    
    if o_Turn:
        Sign = 'O'

    #boolean variable to keep track of whos turn it is, and switch between X/O
    o_Turn = not o_Turn

    ttk.Label(parent, text=Sign, font=('Times', 60, tkFont.BOLD)).place(x=(row*200)+75, y=(col*200)+55)

    board[row][col] = Sign
    button.destroy()

    if check_winner(Sign):
        game_active = False
        winner_window = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        winner_window.title("Winner")
        ttk.Label(winner_window, text=f"Player {Sign} wins!", font=('Times New Roman', 20)).pack(padx=20, pady=20)

        #finds remaining button widgets in the parent widget (the game board)
        for widget in parent.winfo_children():

            #checks whether or not widget is a ttk.Button
            if isinstance(widget, ttk.Button):

                #destroys remaining buttons
                widget.destroy()

def check_winner(player):
    #check rows
    for i in range(3):
        if board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2] == player:
            return True
        

    #check columns
    for j in range(3):
        if board[0][j] == board[1][j] == board[2][j] == player:
            return True

    #check diagonals
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] == player:
        return True
    if board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] == player:
        return True

    return False


#defines the function to open the user guide

def open_user_guide():
    #creates a top level window (appears above all other windows when pressed)
    guide_window = tk.Toplevel(win)

    #sets the name of the new window to "Tic-Tac-Toe Game"
    guide_window.title("User Guide")

    #sets the size of the game window when opened to 600x700
    guide_window.geometry("800x300")

    #doesn't allow the user guide window to be resized
    guide_window.resizable(False, False)

    #creates a frame to contain the labels
    frame = ttk.Frame(guide_window)
    frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both', padx=20, pady=20)

    #creates a new label with the text "How to play:" on the top of the window
    guide_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="User Guide", font=('Times New Roman', 20, 'bold'))
    guide_label.pack(pady=(0, 10), anchor='center')  #centres the label horizontally

    #creates a new text section 
    instructions_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="""
    Hi there! And welcome to my Tic Tac Toe game, made with tkinter.
    
    Here's how to play Tic-Tac-Toe! As you can see, the game is played on a grid that is 3 squares by 3 squares.

    1. The player that starts is X, and the other person is O. You and another player take turns placing X or O into a square.
    2. The first player to get all 3 marks in a row (horizontally, vertically or diagonally) wins the game.
    3. When all the squares are filled and no one has won, the game ends in a tie. AND THAT'S IT! Have fun playing!

    And press reset to play again!""",
    font=('Times New Roman', 12))
    instructions_label.pack(anchor='w')


win = tk.Tk()

#sets window size to 1000 x 600
win.geometry("1000x600")


#sets background image to a tictac
bg = tk.PhotoImage(file = "tictac.png")

#shows image using a label
backgroundimage = tk.Label(win, image=bg) 
backgroundimage.place(x = 0, y = 0)


#sets minimum window resizable size to 500 x 300
win.minsize(500, 300)

#doesn't allow the launcher window to be resized
win.resizable(False, False)

#sets title name of window to Tic-Tac-Toe (name of game)
win.title("Tic-Tac-Toe")

#integrates a new font into tkinter application
tmrn = tkFont.Font(family='Times New Roman', size=15, weight='bold')

#creates a custom style for buttons
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('tmrn.TButton', font=('Times New Roman', 15, 'bold'), padding=(200, 10))  # Increase left and right padding to make the buttons longer


#creates a label with big black letters at the top of the window
title_label = ttk.Label(win, text="Tic-Tac-Toe Game!", font=('Times New Roman', 40, 'bold'), foreground='black')
title_label.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=20)  # Add some padding at the top


#creates a button called 'Play' - takes the user to the actual playable game
play_button = ttk.Button(win, text="Play", command=play_game, style='tmrn.TButton')
play_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=tk.CENTER)  #positions the button just below the center

#creates a button called 'User Guide' - supposed to take the user to another window with how to play
guide_button = ttk.Button(win, text="User Guide", command=open_user_guide, style='tmrn.TButton')
guide_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=tk.CENTER)  #positions the button just below the "Play" button with some padding


win.mainloop()
```

When I play my game, and there is a winner, or a tie, and I would like to play it again, I press the play button on the main window. However, sometimes when I press it, i.e. the 3rd or 4th time that I play it, when I just put a single "X" or a single "O" in a button, it will automatically say "Player X is the winner!" or "Player O is the winner!", even though only 1 square has been filled in. Is there a way to make the play button completely reset the board so I don't get this issue?

I tried to kill the function, which worked, but I don't want to have to kill it and reopen it every time.

Comment: You need to add menu  and click `play_game()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `board` when starting new game:

```py
def play_game():
    ...
    #creates the buttons in the game window, uses configure to later destroy the button after it has been pressed
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            x1 = i * 200
            y1 = j * 200
            button_tile = ttk.Button(game_window)
            button_tile.place(x=x1, y=y1, width=200, height=200)
            button_tile.configure(command=lambda row=i, col=j, btn=button_tile, parent=game_window: button_click(row, col, btn, parent))
            board[i][j] = ''  ### reset board cell
```

Comment: thank you, this works, but I don't want multiple windows to keep opening when I press play, is it possible to just recreate the same play_game window so only one window is open? thanks

Comment: @Pei You can simply close the current game window before starting new one.  If you do want to use the existing game window for the new game, as said, raise another new question.

Comment: @Pei As you have used the solution as your new question, please consider to accept those answers of your previous questions to close them.